# Unity. Some fields go to null on Play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I Mean those fields.

```
[SerializeField]
public Type gameStateType;

[SerializeField]
public IGameStateParams gameStateParams;
```

I made in Editor methods to set those fields up, but, when click **Play** they go null.
I can deal with **Type**(all supported by my system types stored in dictionary, so i can just use their ID to get **Type**), but not with **IWhatever** implemented instance.
Can it be solved?

If not, is there any way to store in scene game object any **IWhatever** implemented instance?

Answer (score 1):

These types (`Type` and interfaces) are not **serializable** .. so while you can of course use editor scripts to pass in values these fields will not be serialized => not saved => Not be initialized on runtime.

When you enter PlayMode all objects in the scene are reloaded => deserialized from scratch => since your values were never serialized they are also not deserialized.

See [Script Serialization -> Serialization Rules](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)

Comment: Is there a way to create any class instance that will always exist and acessable from everywhere until dispose directly called?
I could store some extra data there.